# Wolfram Development Platform - Mixing Text and Formulas

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I am using the Wolfram Development Platform on Mac in Chrome.

I am attempting to write a formula in a plain text cell.
I am following the instructions outlined [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MixingTextAndFormulas.html); i.e., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, and nothing is happening.

I have tried substituting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for <kbd>Cmd</kbd> which also doesn't work.

Is this a known issue?

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: I bet editable inline cells are not supported in wolfram cloud but the only way to be sure is to ask support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Wolfram Cloud does not support two dimensional/linear syntax. That documentation page was exclusively meant for Mathematica/desktop products. Here is a list of keyboard shortcuts which are supported in the Wolfram Cloud: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListingWolframCloud.html

Answer (score 0):

To use maths formulas within text when using WolframCloud you should type <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> if not on Mac).