# Formulas in text cells in Mathematica Online

Tags: formatting, mathematica-online

Is there a way to typeset mathematical equations in text cells in Mathematica Online?

Even if there is no direct support, is there a way to parse LaTeX snippets entered between `$...$` and convert them to formulas, within text cells?

Comment: But check Szabolcs' MaTeX:  http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/9355/

Comment: I assume there's no way to use MaTeX with Mathematica Online?

Comment: To type and display formulas in text cells.

Comment: I tried to edit the question to take off the focus from LaTeX (as it seems that you just want to enter formulas, *not* handle LaTeX).  If the question no longer matches your original intention, please edit or revert.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate: [Wolfram Development Platform - Mixing text and formulas](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/167203/5478) do you agree?